# ¿Cómo encontrar un dato específico usando information_schema?

Tags: mysql

Mi base de datos contiene varias tablas y desconozco totalmente en qué tabla vive mi dato, ni siquiera sé qué tipo de dato es, ¿cómo puedo usar `information_schema` para encontrar ese dato?

Por ejemplo, si tengo un número 5523456789 (pero podría ser un `int`, `char`, `date`...) y quiero saber en qué tabla y qué columna vive ese dato. ¿Cómo se haría?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Opción 1

Si usas PhpMyAdmin, el mismo cuenta con una opción de búsqueda global que puedes utilizar.

### Opción 2

La siguiente procedure busca a través de todas las bases de datos - tablas - columnas:

Lo que hace básicamente es:

- Crea una tabla para almacenar la salida.
- Hace un bucle a través de la tabla COLUMNS de `information_schema` para obtener bases de datos, nombres de tablas y columnas.
- Ejecute una consulta `count (*)` en database.table para cada columna con la cadena de búsqueda apropiada en la condición where.
- Si count (*)> 0, significa que esa columna particular tiene el término de búsqueda.
- Inserta los datos (nombre de la base de datos, nombre de la tabla, nombre de la columna) en una tabla temporal.
- Hace un select * de la tabla para ver los nombres de bases de datos, tablas y columnas correspondientes con el término de búsqueda.

`-- Procedure para buscar en todos los campos de la BD
        DELIMITER $$
        -- Script para recorrer todas las tablas usando Information_Schema
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_table $$
        CREATE PROCEDURE get_table(in_search varchar(50))
        READS SQL DATA
        BEGIN
        DECLARE trunc_cmd VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE search_string VARCHAR(250);
        DECLARE db,tbl,clmn CHAR(50);
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE COUNTER INT;
        DECLARE table_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT concat('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CNT_VALUE FROM ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' WHERE ', column_name,' REGEXP "',in_search,'"') ,table_schema,table_name,column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('network_detail');
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
        -- Truncando la tabla para rellenar los datos para nuevas búsquedas.
        PREPARE trunc_cmd FROM "TRUNCATE TABLE temp_details;";
        EXECUTE trunc_cmd ;
        OPEN table_cur;
        table_loop:LOOP
        FETCH table_cur INTO search_string,db,tbl,clmn;
        -- Ejecutando la búsqueda
        SET @search_string = search_string;
        -- SELECT search_string;
        PREPARE search_string FROM @search_string;
        EXECUTE search_string;
        SET COUNTER = @CNT_VALUE;
        -- SELECT COUNTER;
        IF COUNTER>0 THEN
        -- Insertando resultados requeridos en la tabla
        INSERT INTO temp_details VALUES(db,tbl,clmn);
        END IF;
        IF done=1 THEN
        LEAVE table_loop;
        END IF;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE table_cur;
        -- Mostrando los resultados
        SELECT concat("SELECT * FROM ",t_table, " WHERE ", t_field, " REGEXP '", in_search, "';") FROM temp_details;
        END $$
        DELIMITER ;`

Comment: muchas gracias tu respuesta me aclaro muchas dudas

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido. Puedes votar también la respuesta favorablemente usando la flecha gris que apunta hacia arriba, a la izquierda. Saludos.

Comment: ooo gracias no sabia

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un dump (sqlDump) a tu base de dato(o bases de datos) y buscar el dato ahí.

Comment: Aunque esto podría ser una opción que funcionase (a base de fuerza bruta), no cumpliría con la condición de usar `information_schema` que menciona OP y podría ser un problema si la base de datos es muy grande.